# Split-exact sequence of sheaves of abelian group yields split exact sequence of first cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a variety over a field $k = \bar{k}$. Assume that the Picard scheme $\text{Pic}_{X/k}$ exists and represents the functor Pic on the étale topology. Then we have the tangent space $T_0 \text{Pic}_{X/k}$ is isomorphic to $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. My reference for this is Theorem 9.5.11 of FGA Explained by Fantechi et al.

My question relates to a step in the proof of this. Namely, let $X_{\epsilon}$ be the base change over $k$ with $X$ and $k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$. We have an exact sequence of sheaves of abelian groups:

$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^*_{X_{\epsilon}}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X^{*}\rightarrow 1,$$

where the first map sends $b\rightarrow 1+b\epsilon$. This is a split-exact sequence: we can send an element $b$ of $\mathcal{O}_X^{*}$ to $b+0\epsilon$.

It is then claimed that one can take cohomology to get a split exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{O}^*_{X_{\epsilon}}) \rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{O}_X^{*})\rightarrow 1.$$

Why is this the case? For example, the long exact sequence of cohomology combined with this would then imply that $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X^{*}) = \text{ker}(H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{O}_{X_{\epsilon}})) = 0$, no? But this cannot be right, as we should have $k^*$ contained in the invertible global sections.

Is this a general feature of split exact sequences of sheaves and cohomology?

Comment: If $H^0({\cal O_{X_\epsilon}}) \to H^0({\cal O_X^*})$ surjects, one gets that your kernel above is $0$... Agree? (without needing the triviality of $ H^0({\cal O_X^*})$. )

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this should follow. The kernel must be $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X^*$. If $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X$ surjects onto $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X^*)$ and we know that the composition $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow ... \rightarrow H^0(\mathcal{O}_X$ from the exact sequence above was this surjection, then we could conclude $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X^* = 0$. But it is not clear to me that this is case, nor that we have such a surjection.

Comment: Meanwhile, I am confused - "remind" me - what is the map ${\cal O}_{X_\epsilon} \to {\cal O}_{X}^*$?

Comment: It is the map sending a local section $a+b\epsilon$ to $a$.

Comment: But if $a$ is not invertible, it does not end up in $\cal O^*$ - right? Dont we want ${\cal O}_{X_\epsilon}^*\to{\cal O}_{X}^*$? Namely do you have a typo - a missing $*$ in the middle term in your initial exact sequence?

Comment: Ah, you are correct! And I now agree with what you wrote earlier. For some reason I was convinced that if a map is 0 then the codomain is 0. Thanks!

Comment: so you're ok with the 'split' part of 'split-exact'? (in my first comment I was only addressing the kernel objection of your question.)

Comment: Yes. The splitting of the exact sequence implies the splitting of the $H^i$'s, and so we get an exact sequence for all the $H^i$'s. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cohomology (in any degree) is an additive functor: it takes direct sums to direct sums.  Since a split short exact sequence is just a disguised direct sum, $H^i$ preserves split short exact sequences.

You seem to be confused about what happens on $H^0$.  Just as for $H^1$ (or for any $H^i$) we get a short exact sequence of $H^0$'s, which in this case is

$$0 \to k \to k[\epsilon]^* \to k^* \to 0.$$

The boundary maps in the long exact sequence are all zero.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was getting confused with the boundary maps and convinced myself that the boundary maps being 0 implied the cohomology groups should be 0, but it is cleared up now!

Comment: Typo? - you're missing a $*$ on the middle term of your exact sequence - $k[\epsilon]^*$ -no? (see discussion in the comments to the original question)...

Comment: @peterag : Thanks, now fixed.